How to ensure that all children class of a certain type implement a certain test class
I work in a framework using unittest2.
We have a test that could be used to define a minimal test for all classes deriving of BaseClassA.
I can derive a test from the class BaseTest and override the test input.
However, I would like to enforce the fact that all classes deriving from this base class have to have an implementation of this test.
Currently, someone wrote a registry/list of children classes and runs the tests with a for loop.
This kind of works but for our framework this has limitations because:

each module is assigned to an owner so because all children classes are run in the same module, the errors will be reported as broken by the person who wrote the test with the for loop

our framework runs each test module separately on a grid, so this is not leveraging the framework correctly


Is there a standard way to enforce that children classes must have associated tests implementing a certain number of tests?
